# What is the difference between "activate" and "show" events on Ext.panel.Panel in Extjs 4?

Tags: extjs4

Various Ext components (like [Panel](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel) and [Container](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.container.Container)) have the following events documented:

"[show](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-show)" - Fires after the component is shown when calling the show method.

"[activate](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-activate)" - Fires after a Component has been visually activated.

What I would like to know is:

- What is the difference between these two events?
- Are there specific instances where you would want to use one over
  another?
- At what point of the layout cycle do they both fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate : 
1. It will be triggered, after the component(DOM) has been loaded with all referece link and shown to the user.
2. Layout lifecycle - basic component creation

Show : 
1. It will be triggered, after the component has been shown at the time when we invoke the method "show" of the component. 
2. Layout lifecycle - when we call show method of the component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to run after the view is ready use `afterrender` (or possibly render - they seem to have the same description!).  Show only gets fired when something explicitely calls it.

I've not come across activate.  Maybe that's like focus?  To see where it fits into the chain of events stick in a handler + a break point and see what happens!